# NextJS 14 and Supabase Authentication with Redirect

Tags: redirect, next.js, supabase

I have a NextJS 14 (Typescript) application and using Supabase as SAAS Backend.

My `app/login/page.tsx` file renders the following component:

```js
'use client'
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from 'react-dom';
import { signInUser } from '@/actions/auth'

const initialState = {
  message: "",
}

function SubmitButton(){
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()

  return (
    <button type="submit" aria-disabled={pending}>Bestätigen</button>
  )
}

export default function SignInForm() {

  const [state, sigInAction] = useFormState(signInUser, initialState)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Register!</h2>
      <form action={sigInAction}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            id="password"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <p aria-live="polite" role="status">
          {state?.message}
        </p>
        <div>
          <SubmitButton/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `signInUser` function in `actions/auth.ts` is:

```js
"use server"

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { z } from "zod";
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";


export async function signInUser(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
  console.log("Action")
  const schema = z.object({
    email: z.string().min(1),
    password: z.string().min(1)
  })
  const signUpFormData = schema.parse({
    email: formData.get("email"),
    password: formData.get("password")
  })
  try {
    const cookieStore = cookies()

    const supabase = createServerClient(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
      {
        cookies: {
          get(name: string) {
            return cookieStore.get(name)?.value
          },
          set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options })
          },
          remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value: '', ...options })
          },
        },
      }
    )
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email: signUpFormData.email,
      password: signUpFormData.password,
    })
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    revalidatePath("/")
    console.log("Should redirect now...")
    redirect("/")
  } catch (e){
    return {message: "Error"}
  }
}
```

Here's my middleware.ts:

```js
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Enter Middleware")

  let response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: request.headers,
    },
  })

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return request.cookies.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
        },
      },
    }
  )

  await supabase.auth.getSession();
  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
  // if user is not signed in and the current path is not /login redirect the user to /login
  if (!user && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
    console.log("redirect to /login")
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  // if user is signed in and the current path is /login redirect the user to /
  if (user && request.nextUrl.pathname === '/login') {
    console.log("redirect to /")
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
  }

  return response
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/', '/login'],
}
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
- "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
- "@supabase/ssr": "^0.0.9",
- "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.38.0",
- "@types/node": "20.8.10",
- "@types/react": "18.2.36",
- "@types/react-dom": "18.2.14",
- "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
- "eslint": "8.53.0",
- "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
- "next": "14.0.0",
- "pino": "^8.16.1",
- "pino-logflare": "^0.4.2",
- "postcss": "8.4.31",
- "react": "18.2.0",
- "react-dom": "18.2.0",
- "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
- "redux": "^4.2.1",
- "tailwindcss": "3.3.5",
- "typescript": "5.2.2",
- "zod": "^3.22.4"
```

I know that the authentication works, but unfortunately the redirect doesn't. When reloading the page my middleware automatically redirects the authenticated user.

Can someone please help me why the redirect is not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. I have no idea why, but when I put the `redirect("/")` outside of my `try`-`catch` block it works without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the redirect osutside of the try-catch statement will work, becasue redirect thorw an error NEXT_REDIRECT to stop the render